# Activerecord query taking more time than the raw sql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, activerecord, kaminari, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Active record query using kaminari is taking more time to give results than the raw sql. The table contains 80 million records.

```
Ticket.order("tickets.id desc").page(1).without_count.per(10)
```

The above code generates below sql:

Ticket Load (**89598.2ms**)

```
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         raw_sql_.*,
         rownum raw_rnum_ 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               "TICKETS".* 
            FROM
               "TICKETS" 
            ORDER BY
               TICKETS.ID DESC 
         )
         raw_sql_ 
      WHERE
         rownum <= (:a1 + :a2)
   )
WHERE
   raw_rnum_ > :a1 
[["OFFSET", 0], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

The same sql when executed in rails console or database, takes **28.3ms**

Not able to find why active record takes more time. The difference between the two timings are very high.

Comment: Does the same thing happens when you just use `Ticket.limit(10)`? (no = probably an issue introduced by kaminari, yes = probably not related to kaminari)

Comment: How do you enter the query when you run it manually? Perhaps there is a difference if the rownum filter uses bind variables (:a1 + :a2) or if it uses a constant (10)? Oracle may decide to use a full scan as it thinks you want to read many records, when in fact you want only a few.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Ticket.limit(10) does take less time around 25 ms.  when entering the query manually, i am replacing the bind variable (:a1 + :a2) as (11)